# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a simple `login` module using laravel 5.4 which is working fine and I also set `session` value to get access of particular user, not the problem is that when I click on `logout` button it redirect my page to `login` page which is perfect but when I access `dashboard` page directly on browser then it show me an error i.e `Invalid argument supplied foreach()`

How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

dashboard.blade.php

```
<?php
    if(!isset($data))
    {
        header('location:{{url("login")}}');
    }
?>
@foreach($data as $row)
    <h3>Welcome, {{ $row->username }}</h3>
@endforeach
<a href="{{url('logout')}}">Logout</a>
```

Mycontroller.php

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        $user = Session::get('user');
        return view('user.dashboard',['data'=>$user]);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Comment: You probably should change `if(!isset($data))` to `if(!is_array($data))`

Comment: nothing change `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (0)` @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Can you {{$data}} before foreach and delete foreach to show what you get in $data or `dd($user)` before return in your controller. @darkshadow

Answer (score 0):

Try **empty()** function in spite of  **isset()** function

and also need to check the $data **is_array()** or **is_object()**.

```
<?php
if(empty($data))
{
    header('location:{{url("login")}}');
}
?>

@if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
  @foreach($data as $row)
         <h3>Welcome, {{ $row->username }}</h3>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a problem in your controller function, where you using $user define it as an array like:

```
$user['data'] = Session::get('user');
```

and just return it like that:

```
return view('user.dashboard',$user);
```

after that simply run your dashboard.blade.php file